# How can i get proxy settings with wmi?

Tags: windows-7, proxy, wmi, wmic

I try this in cmd `wmic path win32_proxy`,

but get

`ERROR: Description = Invalid class`

OS: Windows 7 64bit

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're doing it quite correctly, but it seems like the class `Win32_Proxy` isn't available on your computer.

Which, isn't surprising, as it isn't available here either:

```
PS C:\> gwmi -Class win32_proxy
Get-WmiObject : Invalid class
At line:1 char:5
+ gwmi <<<<  -Class win32_proxy
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

This appears to be because it's no longer available in Windows 7, as [it is no longer available post-XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> **End of client support**: Windows XP

Comment: Do you know what class it is transformed in?

Comment: @VladimirNani I tried looking around, but I couldn't find any class in the 10-minutes of Googling. It seemed like most hinted towards going with native C-functions, which isn't... quite as simple. Otherwise, you're better off using the registry for it.

Comment: That`s what I did eventually. Thanks.